# Can I add a "virtual" folder in WebStorm to easily add and hide config files or is there a feature for easily toggling visibility for specific files?

Tags: javascript, npm, sublimetext, webstorm, web-frontend

Seeing all my config files at the root directory is a huge pet peeve of mine since they are typically set up at the beginning of the project and only tweaked now and then. I know I can hide these in WebStorm, but then unhiding them becomes a hassle.

Ideally I would create something like a "virtual" folder which doesn't change any of the physical directories and I can simply expand to see all my config files. Visual Studio has something similar called a "solution" folder.

For example, I'd like to be able to create a "virtual" folder called .config and then drag all my config files. I could then easily collapse this.

- .config

  - .bowerrc
  - .editorconfig
  - .jscsrc
  - .jshintrc
  - .bower.json
  - .gulp.config.js
  - .favicon.ico
  - .karma.conf.js
  - bower.json
  - package.json
  - README.md

Alternatively, the ability to easily toggle visibility of specific files or folders would be a great feature.

It's a bit of a hack, but for Sublime Text, I have a simple script for toggling file_exclude_patterns and folder_exclude_patterns. I'm currently toying with WebStorm for some future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With 'scopes', you can create custom groups of files and folders.
   https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/scopes.html
2. You can assign a color to that scope. Everything in the scope will show as that color in the sidebar, and when you open a file from that scope, its tab will be that color too!
   https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/add-edit-color-label-dialog.html
3. The project sidebar on the left shows all files and folders by default. However, you can filter your files by your custom scope/group:

   - Click on dropdown menu in the upper left where it says 'Project' (next to the crosshair-looking thing).
   - Select the scope you defined.
   - Now your sidebar only shows the files in that scope!

[image: Voila!]

Comment: Just upload the screen-shot, embed the link and someone can help inline it for you (in any case, upvoted, you should have 10+ now :) )

Answer (score 0):

John,

What I did to resolve this was to mark everything I 'wanted to see' as a favorite, including folders, and replace the project tab with the favorites tab as my primary means of project navigation. This way I see only what I want to see and nothing else.